# Add video to page on Button click

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner JS user, and I am trying to get a video to play on fullscreen and replace an invisible div further down on the page. I started with a guide from [Chris Ferdinandi](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-play-a-video-in-full-screen-mode-when-its-thumbnail-is-clicked-with-vanilla-js/).

In his guide, the video replaces the image that is clicked. I would like to have the div later down on the page to be replaced on the click.

Any guidance would be great!

HTML

```
<a data-video="480459339" class="stylsheetref" href="#" target="">Watch the Tour</a>
<div id="video-replace"></div>
```

Javascript (modified from [this guide](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-play-a-video-in-full-screen-mode-when-its-thumbnail-is-clicked-with-vanilla-js/))

```
<script>
   if (!Element.prototype.requestFullscreen) {
    Element.prototype.requestFullscreen = Element.prototype.mozRequestFullscreen || Element.prototype.webkitRequestFullscreen || Element.prototype.msRequestFullscreen;
}

// Listen for clicks
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    //Set invisible Div (new code added by me)
    var videonew = '#video-replace');
 
    // Check if clicked element is a video link
    var videoId = event.target.getAttribute('data-video');
    if (!videoId) return;

    // Create iframe
    var iframe = document.createElement('div');
    iframe.innerHTML = '<p>x</p><iframe width="560" height="960" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + videoId + '?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    var video = iframe.childNodes[1];

    // Replace the image with the video
    event.target.parentNode.replaceChild(video, videonew);

    // Enter fullscreen mode
    video.requestFullscreen();
    
}, false);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are problems in your code.

`var videonew = '#video-replace');` there's an orphan `)`, since you are using this in the `replaceChild``method I assume you want the variable to reference to an element.

So change it to

`var videonew = document.querySelector('#video-replace');`

Pro tip: Using the Developer console during development can help you figure out such errors in your code.